# Как правильно windows.location или windows.location.assign?

Tags: javascript

Хочу по javascript перейти на новую страницу. Как правильно?

```
windows.location = 'new_page';
```

или

```
windows.location.assign('new_page');
```

Или можно использовать и так и так?

Answer (score 2):

- `window.location.replace()` изменяет текущий адрес и запись в истории браузера. Вернуться назад на эту страницу не получится;
- `window.location.assign()` загружает новый документ, оставляя в истории ссылку на старый;
- присвоение `window.location` URL или изменение любого его свойства [аналогичны вызову `window.location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location).

Comment: А где написано, что не желательно?

Comment: Пожалуй исправлю, действительно. Отложилась в памяти проблема с IE, но свидетельств этому нигде не нашел. Разве что явно вызвать функцию может быть лучше, чем неявно получить перезагрузку при изменении компонентов `location`

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее будет использовать:

```
window.location.href = 'new_page';
```

Comment: А где про это можно почитать?

Comment: Например, здесь http://www.corelangs.com/js/basics/redirect.html или здесь http://javascript.ru/window-location

Comment: В скинутых вами ссылками везде пишут так: windows.location = 'new_page'; ))

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать. При изменении любого свойства или самого объекта, кроме `hash`, документ перезагружается как бы вызывая `window.location.assign()`. Следующие 3 строчки равносильны:

```
window.location = 'http://site.com';
window.location.href = 'http://site.com';
window.location.assign('http://site.com')
```

При этом во всех случаях в истории браузера запись добавляется.

Еще можно открыть в новой вкладке, но только при совершении юзером действия

```
window.open('http://site.com','name','height=200,width=150');
```